# How to update two columns from one select

Tags: mysql

Can I combine this in to one?

```
UPDATE 1_packages k 
SET 
    rrp = (SELECT 
            SUM(u.quantity * p.rrp) * (sum(p.price_each <> 0 and p.rrp = 0) = 0)
        FROM
            1_packages_plu u
                INNER JOIN
            1_products p ON u.fk_products_id = p.id
        WHERE
            fk_packages_id = k.id)
;

UPDATE 1_packages k 
SET 
    rrp_inc = (SELECT 
            SUM(u.quantity * p.rrp_inc) * (sum(p.price_each <> 0 and p.rrp_inc = 0) = 0)
        FROM
            1_packages_plu u
                INNER JOIN
            1_products p ON u.fk_products_id = p.id
        WHERE
            fk_packages_id = k.id)
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple, Try

```
UPDATE 1_packages k 
   SET rrp = (SELECT SUM(u.quantity * p.rrp) * (sum(p.price_each <> 0 and p.rrp = 0) = 0)
             FROM 1_packages_plu u INNER JOIN 1_products p ON u.fk_products_id = p.id 
             WHERE fk_packages_id = k.id),
       rrp_inc = (SELECT SUM(u.quantity * p.rrp_inc) * (sum(p.price_each <> 0 and p.rrp_inc = 0) = 0)
                 FROM 1_packages_plu u INNER JOIN 1_products p ON u.fk_products_id = p.id 
                 WHERE fk_packages_id = k.id)
```

Comment: Ya that was a mistake, you need to enclosed from clause also with sub query, look for my updated answer.

Comment: @StephenBouffe try to change u and p in 2nd block to some non-used letters

Comment: OK taking it one step further. If I have another column in 1_packages called 'sn' how to update this when either rrp or rrp_inc has changed?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET column_one = "value one", 
    column_two = "value two"
WHERE condition
```